# P2P connection mitigated by server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, pnrp

I'm writing a system in C# that is composed of 1 desktop application (I call it the "host") connected to multiple "client" applications over the internet. The "host" should be able to retrieve status information (at the very least whether the client application is running) as well as send files to the client computers. Client computers do not have to see or communicate with each other. Client applications will be running 24/7, but the host application will only be running when the user wants to check on the PCs running the client applications.

I have done a fair bit of reading on microsoft's PNRP, and think I will use a system based on this to mitigate the connections between the host and clients - i.e. each Client application detects a WAN IP change, and reports its new IP to a linux server that I have. When the host application wants to connect, it wil connect to the server, authenticate, and grab the list of WAN IPs of the client applications.

From here, I would like to directly connect from the host application to each client application. In order to alleviate loading on the server, I do not want to send files or status info through the server. What would be the best way to do this? Each client application may be behind Firewalls, NAT, etc. and I will not have the ability to port forward manually (although I can use uPnP when it works).

PS - Any PNRP alternatives you would suggest? I would use PNRP directly, except (1) for security reasons I need to use my own seed server (linux) instead of the microsoft PNRP seed servers, and its my understanding that PNRP is windows-only and (2) PNRP only works over ipv6, which the networks (and ISPs) may not always support.

Comment: TCP Socket, but it is blocked by firewalls.